# C# Regex matching using a varible

Tags: c#, regex

I am most familiar with PowerShell and have recently moved into using C# as my primary language. In PowerShell it's possible to do the following

```
$var1 = "abc"
"abc" -match "$var1"
```

This results in a true statement.

I would like to do be able to do the same thing in C#. I know that you can use interpolation with C# and I have tries various ways of trying to use Regex.Match() with no luck.

Example:

```
string toMatch = "abc";

var result = Regex.Match("abc", $"{{toMatch}}");
var a = Regex.Match("abc", $"{{{toMatch}}}");
var b = Regex.Match("abc", $"{toMatch}");
var c = Regex.Match(toMatch,toMatch);
```

None of the above seems to work. I am not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible in C#. Ideally I'd like to be able to use a combination of variables and Regex for a match. Something even like this `Regex.Match(varToMatch,$"{{myVar}}\\d+\\w{4}")`

edit:
After reading some answers here and trying some code out it appears that my real issue is trying to match up against a directory path. Something like "C:\temp\abcfile". For example:

```
string path = @"C:\temp\abc";
            string path2 = @"C:\temp\abc";
            string fn = path.Split('\\').LastOrDefault();

            path = Regex.Escape(path);
            path2 = Regex.Escape(path2);

            Regex rx = new Regex(path);

            var a = Regex.Match(path.Split('\\').Last().ToString(), $"{fn}");
//Example A works if I split and match on just the file name.

            var b = Regex.Match(path, $"{rx}");
//Example B does not work, even though it's a regex object.
            var c = Regex.Match(path, $"{{path}}");
//Example C I've tried one, two, and three sets of parenthesis with no luck
            var d = Regex.Match(path,path);
// Even a direct variable to variable match returns 0 results.
```

Comment: Your code works fine (but only if you don't add extra braces).  What' the problem?

Comment: You need `Regex.Escape`.

Comment: Use `$@` instead of double-escaping backslashes.

Comment: I've tried combinations of $ and $@ and I can never seem to get it to work for me...

Comment: You can just do: `var c = Regex.Match("abc", toMatch);`, then check `c.Success`

Comment: Your return type on Match is not a bool, you can check .success or that at least one match was found

Comment: The problem is all the different variants I've tried I have yet to actually get a successful match. My end goal is to compare a user entered path to the files in a folder and auto increment the user provided file path as needed. I thought I could do this by creating a string variable from the user entered path and then looping through the contents of a folder/directory and doing a match check on each entry.

Comment: Please post the details of the real problem you have.

Comment: It looks to me like you need to systematically learn about each part of the language syntax and library functions separately.  It could take forever trying to come up with working code by testing variations, and likewise for those you're asking to help you.  For example, if your combinations of $ and $@ fail, I'm guessing from your code and descriptions that you don't really understand what those mean. It's a tall order to ask a question about regex, comparing that to PowerShell behavior, all the while trying to figure out c# syntax. This is not meant to be insulting or rude, just truthful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have it right in the last example, so perhaps the issue is that you're expecting a bool result instead of a `Match` result?

Hopefully this small example helps:

```
int a = 123;
string b = "abc";
string toMatch = "123 and abc";

var result = Regex.Match(toMatch, $"{a}.*{b}");

if (result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found a match!");
}
```

Comment: Your example works great. Maybe the problem I'm having is with escaping characters since my end goal is matching two directory paths. Even using Regex.Escape() doesn't seem to quite work.

Comment: Ah, ok. You should update your question to reflect that!